# List has no rows for assignment to SObject: Trigger.updatephones: line 4, column 1

Tags: error

```
trigger updatephones on Contact (after insert) {
List<Account> acc=new List<Account>();
for(Contact c:trigger.new){
     Account a=[Select Id,Name,phone From Account Where Id=:c.AccountId];
     a.phone=c.phone;
     acc.add(a);
 }
update acc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is coming because for some contact accountid is coming blank at line 4 while doing SOQL.

Your code can be simplified in following way

```
trigger updatephones on Contact (after insert) {
     Map<Id, Account> accounts = new map<Id, account>();
     for(Contact c:trigger.new){
       //Check for Accountid null
       if(c.Accountid!=null)
       {
           //putting in map so that code can handle same Account update from multiple contact otherwise duplicate Id error will occur.
           accounts.put(c.accountid, new account(id=c.accountid, phone=c.phone));
       }

     }

     update accounts.values();
}
```

Comment: `if(acc.size()>0)` or `if(!acc.isEmpty())` is no longer needed. Stop using it.

Comment: ...also, this code will fail if multiple contacts are updated on the same account in the same trigger.

Comment: Hey @sfdcfox is SFDC has handling that now ?

Comment: Yes, `update acc` will automatically perform a no-op update (e.g. DML rows and DML calls limits will not update) when the list is empty. Do try it out.

Comment: The code should look more like `Map<Id, Account> accounts = new map<Id, account>(); for(Contact c: trigger.new) { if(record.accountid != null) { accounts.put(c.accountid, new account(id=c.accountid, phone=c.phone)); } } update accounts.values();`

Comment: You were basically correct, so +1, it just needs some TLC. Good answer!

Comment: Thanks, Good catch, point taken. I have updated the code with your input.